# Android - Align view center with center of last child in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

[image]

My problem is similar to this one:

[Android - Align view center to bottom of other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697099/android-align-view-center-to-bottom-of-other-view)

But id differs in a significant detail. I don't want to center the view with the end of the `RecyclerView`, but with the center of it's **last child view**. So I **can't** just use:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_view"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_view"
```

Would there be a solution for this case?

Comment: probably you'll have to use recyclerview with different itemTypes, check this link, might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/2931124

Comment: You did say ConstraintLayout, so the question is the RecyclerView or horizontal or vertical orientation.?

Comment: @Cheticamp Horizontal orientation

Comment: So the RecyclerView items slide left and right. What happens to the custom view when that top/right item moves? Does it move with it or does it stay? (I'm assuming it stays.)

Comment: If you know something definite about the relationship of the width of the items to the width of the RecyclerView such as "the width of the RecyclerView is always four times the width of each item", then you could probably do something in XML. If not, then you will need to do some coding to place a guideline or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the last view that you want at center inside the recycle_list_item.xml because here you can align the lastView vertically center  .
then do some logic  in onBindViewHolder()

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BusStopViewHolder holder, int position) {
       
        if(position==viewList.size()-1){
            
         
            holder.lastView.setVisibility(View.Visible);

        }
       else  holder.lastView.setVisibility(View.Gone);}
```